# How to display multiple ck editor in array in php passing same id?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

I am doing a project in codeigniter and I came across a problem of displaying multiple ckeditor for *objective answer to a question* in my view.

```
   <div class="col-md-6">   
   <textarea id="objective_answer" name="objective_answer"><?php echo set_value('objective_answer', $answer); ?></textarea>   
    <?php echo form_ckeditor(array('id'=>'objective_answer'));  ?>

     </div>

    <?php  }  ?>
```

The above code displays one ck editor fine.But I have to show lets say 4 ckeditor for writing 4 objective answers to a question. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Put different ids. The `id` html attribute should be unique on the page.

Comment: +1 facing the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a counter and set unique ids for the text areas:

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){?>

<div class="col-md-6">   
    <textarea id="objective_answer<?php echo $i;?>" name="objective_answer">
        <?php echo set_value('objective_answer', $answer); ?>
    </textarea>   
    <?php echo form_ckeditor(array('id'=>'objective_answer'.$i));  ?>
</div>
<?php }
```